# Generate object files from source files located in multiple folders

Tags: makefile, g++, msys2

I want to generate my executable (`TARGET = $(BUILD_DIR)/MySDLProgram`) that is dependent of the object files (`OBJS = $(wildcard $(BUILD_DIR)/*.o`), whose are dependents of source files located in `src/application` and `src/engine`. How I should proceed?

I keep getting this error:

[Note that Makefile not found the object files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D9br.png)

This is my Makefile:

```
#CC specifies which compiler we're using
CC = g++

# Directories
SRC_DIR = src
BUILD_DIR = build

TARGET = $(BUILD_DIR)/MySDLProgram

# Source files
SRC_DIRS = src/engine src/application
SRCS = $(foreach dir, $(SRC_DIRS), $(wildcard $(dir)/*.cpp))

OBJS = $(wildcard $(BUILD_DIR)/*.o)

# INCLUDE_PATHS specifies the additional include paths we'll need
INCLUDE_PATHS = -Iheader

# COMPILER_FLAGS specifies the additional compilation options we're using
#   -w suppresses all warnings
#   -Wl,-subsystem,windows gets rid of the console window
# COMPILER_FLAGS = -w -Wl,-subsystem,windows
COMPILER_FLAGS = -g -O0 -Wall -std=c++11

#LINKER_FLAGS specifies the libraries we're linking against
LINKER_FLAGS = -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_mixer -lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2

.PHONY: all

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(foreach dir, $(SRC_DIRS), $(dir))/%.cpp | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(CC) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) $(LINKER_FLAGS) $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR):
    mkdir -p $@

exec: $(BIN)
    $(BIN).exe

clean:
    @$(RM) -rv $(BUILD_DIR)/*
```

These are the commands that I want to run:

```
$ g++ -Iheader -g -O0 -Wall -std=c++11 -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_mixer -lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2 src/engine/Game.cpp -c -o build/Game.o

$ g++ -Iheader -g -O0 -Wall -std=c++11 -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_mixer -lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2 src/engine/Music.cpp -c -o build/Music.o

$ g++ -Iheader -g -O0 -Wall -std=c++11 -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_mixer -lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2 src/engine/State.cpp -c -o build/State.o

$ g++ -Iheader -g -O0 -Wall -std=c++11 -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_mixer -lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2 src/engine/Sprite.cpp -c -o build/Sprite.o

$ g++ -Iheader -g -O0 -Wall -std=c++11 -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_mixer -lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2 src/application/Main.cpp -c -o build/Main.o

$ g++ -g -O0 -Wall -std=c++11 -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_mixer -lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2 build/Main.o build/Game.o build/Music.o build/Sprite.o build/State.o
```

---

I'm using MSYS2 environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot work:

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(foreach dir, $(SRC_DIRS), $(dir))/%.cpp | $(BUILD_DIR)
```

What does this expand to after the variables are resolved?  You get this:

```
build/%.o: src/engine src/application/%.cpp | build
                    ^^
```

Which is clearly not what you wanted.  Even if you fix your definition to do what you probably expected:

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(foreach dir, $(SRC_DIRS), $(dir)/%.cpp) | $(BUILD_DIR)
                                                    ^^^^^^^
```

which gives:

```
build/%.o: src/engine/%.cpp src/application/%.cpp | build
```

what does this mean to make?  It means that in order to match this pattern rule, each `build/XXX.o` file has to find (or be able to build) a matching `src/engine/XXX.cpp` **AND** a matching `src/application/XXX.cpp`.  Basically each object file has BOTH source files as a prerequisite.

Since none of your files meet that criteria, this rule cannot match ever and so make will not be able to find a way to build the target `build/XXX.o`.

You have to write two different rules here, one for each directory:

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: src/engine/%.cpp | $(BUILD_DIR)
        ...
$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: src/application/%.cpp | $(BUILD_DIR)
        ...
```

Alternatively you can use [VPATH](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html) to ask make to go look in various directories, like this:

```
VPATH = $(SRC_DIRS)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp | $(BUILD_DIR)
        ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! Besides the Makefile documentation, do you know some guide that cover the essential of Makefile without being much superficial that you could recommend me?

Comment: The GNU make manual https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html is the prime resource.  There are some good books and other things mentioned in the **References** section on this site: http://make.mad-scientist.net/